# Java thread both RUNNABLE and in Object.wait

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, locking

On two servers I now have recently started getting an issue - using Tomcat, the NIO connectors, and Java 7 one of the threads has now started hanging at an impossible spot. The threads in question are all http-request handlers and there are filters configured for various purposes - the spot that seems to be a question is where we are doing a basic IP check against the user. I've reproduced the stacktraces that seem to be at fault below (with non-essential data removed), as well as the line of code that exec-7 is apparently stuck on.

```
"http-80-exec-7" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000000e89000 nid=0x722a in Object.wait() [0x00007f7438ab5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at com.web.utilities.server.Entity.makeIdentifierMultiLingual(Entity.java:5469)
    [[ ... no locks or anything here, just lots of irrelevant depth ... ]]
    at com.web.utilities.server.Entity.find(Entity.java:1953)
    at com.web.portal.entities.TypeRegistry.theTypeRegistry(TypeRegistry.java:118)
    - locked <0x0000000361518798> (a java.lang.Class for com.web.portal.entities.TypeRegistry)
    at com.web.portal.entities.TypeRegistry.theTypeRegistryReverse(TypeRegistry.java:206)
    - locked <0x0000000361518798> (a java.lang.Class for com.web.portal.entities.TypeRegistry)
    at com.web.portal.entities.TypeEncoding.theTypeEncoding(TypeEncoding.java:2355)
    [[ request stuff ]]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"http-80-exec-4" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000000ebc800 nid=0x7225 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f7438fba000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at com.web.portal.entities.TypeRegistry.theTypeRegistryReverse(TypeRegistry.java:203)
    - waiting to lock <0x0000000361518798> (a java.lang.Class for com.web.portal.entities.TypeRegistry)
    at com.web.portal.entities.TypeEncoding.theTypeEncoding(TypeEncoding.java:2355)
    [[ ... no locks or anything here, just lots of irrelevant depth ... ]]
    at com.web.portal.SiteController.init(SiteController.java:5165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
    - locked <0x0000000324a28358> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:809)
    - locked <0x0000000324a28358> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:883)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:722)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:2214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

What I don't get is how the thread has been hung on `makeIdentifierMultiLingual` for a half hour or better - always that line, which does not have any `wait` code on it - so how does it think it is in `Object.wait`?. How is it **possible** to have a thread both `RUNNABLE` and in `Object.wait`? Here is the line in question:

```
private String makeIdentifierMultiLingual(String identifier) {
  try {
    ==> if (SiteTranslator.getTargetLanguage() != SiteTranslator.getDefaultLanguage()) {
```

Now both of those methods access ThreadLocal variables, but the stacktrace doesn't point to those lines of code. I've been wondering if the stacktraces are somehow wrong, but I don't know how they could be as I created them with the standard `jstack` executable (on Ubuntu servers). The root issue at hand here, so far as I can tell, is that I have a thread basically causing a deadlock by sleeping forever while holding a fairly common lock/class, while reporting itself to be and appearing to be RUNNABLE - is there a better or deeper way to analyze that issue?